# Navigating to subfolders in drive through Google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make a simple database that collects previous exams and other documents.

Here is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
     
  <script>
    function UploadFile() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var file = document.getElementById('attach').files[0];
      reader.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('fileContent').value=reader.result;
        document.getElementById('filename').value=file.name;
        document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit();
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    var majorObject = {
  "EE": ["EE251/250", "EE23131"], //add other majors and course like "major": ["course1", "course2"],
  "IE": ["IE321", "IE332"]
}
window.onload = function() {
  var majorSel = document.getElementById("major");
  var courseSel = document.getElementById("course");
  var chapterSel = document.getElementById("chapter");
  for (var x in majorObject) {
    majorSel.options[majorSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  majorSel.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters- and courses- dropdowns
    
    courseSel.length = 1;
    
    
    var z = majorObject[majorSel.value];
    console.log(z);
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      courseSel.options[courseSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
    } 
  }  
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  
    <form id="uploadForm" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwKNrxPq3UvrI9KO1AFz4YcZBrIydjn5MC6pZS59Z7y-_5zuSe_Z1Z0Jz6gaV_XnvoZ/exec" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="fileContent" id="fileContent">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="filename" id="filename">
        
        <label> MAjor : </label><select name="major" id="major">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select major</option>
        </select>
        <label> Course :</label> <select name="course" id="course">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Please select major first</option>
        </select>
        <label> Contact : </label><input required type="text" value="" name="contact" id="contact">
        <label> FileType :</label> 
        <select name="type" id="type">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Type</option>
          <option value="TestBank">TestBank</option>
          <option value="Quiz">Quiz</option>
          <option value="Slide">Slide</option>
          
          
        </select>
        <label> LinkedIn Account:</label><input type="text" value="" name="linkedinUrl" id="linkedinUrl">   
        
      </form>
      <input required id="attach" name="attach" type="file"/>
      <input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="UploadFile();" />
</body>
</html>
```

The client should select the major and the course and the type of document (quiz, book, etc).
Then the program should collect the data and deliver it to the right folder in Drive according to the client's selections
For example, If a client entered IE, IE321, quiz.
On Gdrive, The program should enter the IE folder, IE321 folder, Quiz folder, Then it drops the uploaded files by the client.

My problem is that every time someone submits the form the program just creates a folder in the main Drive folder. Also, it does not accumulate data.

Here is the App script code:

```
function doPost(e) {

  try {
    var data = e.parameter.fileContent;
    var filename = e.parameter.filename;
    var course = e.parameter.course;
    var major = e.parameter.major;
    var types = e.parameter.type;
    var result=uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data,filename,major,course,e,types);
    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(result) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, major, course,e,types) {
  
  try {
    var dropbox = "Demo";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      var selectedmajor = folder[0].getFoldersByName(major);       
      var selectedcourse = selectedmajor[0].getFoldersByName(course);       
      var selectedtype = selectedcourse[0].getFoldersByName(types);
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(selectedtype);
    }
   
    var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
        bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
        blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file);
        var file = folder.createFolder([major, course].join("-")).createFile(blob);
        var fileUrl=file.getUrl();
        
        //Generating Email Body
        var html =  
    '<body>' + 
      '<h2> New Job Application </h2>' +
        '<p>Name : '+e.parameters.name+'</p>' +
        '<p>Email : '+e.parameters.email+'</p>' +
        '<p>Contact : '+e.parameters.contact+'</p>' +
        '<p>Skill Sets : '+e.parameters.skillsets+'</p>' +
        '<p>LinkedIn Url : '+e.parameters.linkedinUrl+'</p>' +
        '<p>File Name  : '+e.parameters.filename+'</p>' +
        '<p><a href='+file.getUrl()+'>Resume Link</a></p><br />' +
    '</body>';
    
    record_data(e,fileUrl);
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, "New Job Application Recieved","New Job Application Request Recieved",{htmlBody:html});
        return file.getUrl();
  } catch (f) {
    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"file upload failed",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(f) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug it? You are the one with all of the data so you should be the one to debug it.

Comment: Are you sure the application is executed as someone who has access to folder `Demo`?